# Header with Image: Page number disappearing after firstpage

Tags: fancyhdr, lastpage

When I compile the following code, there's no page number after the first page. If I comment out the Geometry command at the top of the code, the page number appears well beyond the printable page.

What's happening to all the pages after the title page once I try to ad an image in the header of the first page only?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{newstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \rhead{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{banner}}
}

\pagestyle{newstyle}

\begin{document}


\maketitle
\thispagestyle{newstyle}
\lipsum[1-2]

\newpage

\lipsum[1-2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topic: replace `\thepage \hspace{1pt} of` by `\thepage\ of`

Comment: Move `\pagestyle{newstyle}` inside the `document` environment.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[margin=3cm,showframe]{geometry}` to see the space reserved for the header and you will find out that it could be too shorter to fit the image inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To use `\maketitle` you have to define on preamble at least `\title{}` or `\author{}`.
2. Load the package `geometry` with the `showframe`option so you can have total control of margins configuration.

`\usepackage[margin=3cm,showframe]{geometry}`

3. Since you are inserting an image in the header you will have to adjust the header's height with the option `head=` within `geometry`.
4. Finally, call your page style as `\begin{document}\pagestyle{newstyle}`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,showframe,head=8mm,a5paper]{geometry} % a5paper just for demo

\fancypagestyle{newstyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \rhead{\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=5mm]{example-image-a}}
}

\title{title}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{newstyle}

\maketitle
\lipsum[2]

\newpage    
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ps:** note that `\maketitle` does not use your page style, it uses the `plain` one.